# Read Lock in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, locking

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way to acquire a read lock in Rails (for a table). I know these are not typically ideal, but my use case seems to require one:

There are a limited number of tickets available in an allocation, and I want to have a read lock for the entire transaction as follows:

1. Check there are enough tickets left
2. Assign all of them to this transaction (by creating rows in the ticket table)

If two requests were to perform step one at the time, it might be possible to create too many ticket objects, since the number of available tickets has changed in the mean time (race condition)

Is there another way to do this that follows the rails mentality better, or am I stuck with manually locking and unlocking as required?

(Ideally the solution would be database-agnostic)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you in regard of having to synchronize access to the database in your usecase. Besides using a lock you could serialize your database operations using a queue: only one operation has access to your database at one point in time - I think this is a more highlevel model of managing concurrent access to a resource. Locks are sensible to deadlocks and I would try to avoid those at all costs.

Another - but database dependent - strategy that could solve your problem would use a transaction isolation level of "serializable".

Comment: Using a queue makes sense to me, I just find it strange that ActiveRecord (and indeed, most ORMs don't offer any sort of table locking).

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, i don't remember active_record managing database-level locks. Whole "rails-way" paradigm partly goes against many good-old dba idioms(take STI for instance). So, yeah, you're stuck with manual locking. You can implement it with some mutex class(or whatever else) though.

Second option is rethinking your solution. You can manage pretty well with some kind of capped collection/queue.

Comment: Not a fan of the way it does that, but (as with my comment to @Tom's answer) a queue of some sort seems to be the way to go. Not sure the best approach, because ideally it wouldn't rely on shared memory or anything like that.

Comment: You should use queue with atomic push/pop operations. For example, redis is good language-agnostic tool for the task.